# Is it allowed to say ameen when imam asks Dua after every prayer?

Tags: salat, dua

I heard that duas cannot be asked in group and it should be asked alone but In my country, after every prayer , after completing the dhikr , imam asks Dua and all people say ameen thinking that the Dua imam is asking will be accepted for them . So is the imam doing right and duas will be accepted or is it wrong ?

Comment: "I heard that duas cannot be asked in group and it should be asked alone" <-- You heard from who? And why do you respect their opinion over that of your imam?

Answer (score -2):

**No**

Every innovation in the Deen will not be accepted, and you should not say Ameen to that duas. saying Ameen to what he is saying is like you are accepting what he is doing.

> 'Aishah (May Allah be pleased with her) reported:
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "If anyone introduces in our matter something  which does not belong to it, will be rejected".
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> The narration in Muslim says: "If anybody introduces a practice which
> is not authenticated by me, it is to be rejected".

[Hadith Reference](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/169)

Comment: This answer is in serious need of references.

Comment: What about the hadith in the answer?

Comment: The hadith implies that bid'ah is bad, but we only have your word here that the action in question counts as bi'dah in the first place. I'd recommend reading the meta thread at https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/598/22 to better understand the sorts of answers we encourage here.

Comment: I think, that my answer meets the two criteria in your answer in that thread.
It is not mere opinion.
It comes from an authoritative source.
"but we only have your word here that the action in question counts as bi'dah in the first place." 
Actually the prophet (PBUH) didn't do that and if he did something like that, there will be some evidence for it.

Comment: And we're just supposed to assume that you (a) know everything that the prophet did, ever, and (b) are thoroughly familiar with all the evidences thereof? Because that's asking a lot from the single word "No". See also: https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/355/22